# Run PHP function when img clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform a function when an image is clicked in PHP? I know it can be done in Javascript. For example, when `foo.png` is clicked, the following function will run.

```
function example() {
    header('Location: example.php');
}
```

Comment: Nope. PHP is a server side language. As far as it is concerned the browser does not really exist.

Comment: You may want to show all relevant code for a complete answer.

Comment: only if your image is contained in a `<form>` and you call Submit but i don't think that is what you want based on the function you showed as an example make the image a hyperlink...... Or explain what you want to accomplish better  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is run on the server, and is used before and while creating the page -- and then it is submitted to the browser for rendering.

Once the page is rendered and displayed to the user, all PHP processing has stopped and the page has been served to the client. Server code no longer runs - its time has passed.

Once in the browser, only client-side code can run (javascript). Particularly when interacting with the user, client side code is all you can use.

However, you can also use client-side code (javascript/jQuery) to interact with the user (detect a click or mouse movement) and then use AJAX to send data over to another server-side PHP file. The PHP file will "wake-up" as it receives the data, and it can do some additional server-side stuff -- such as use the received data to perform a DB look-up, then take the new DB data and create some HTML code and send that back to the page. This new HTML code can be injected onto the page in the success (or `.done()` ) function of the AJAX code block and new data can appear on the page without refreshing or navigating away from the current page.

But for actually detecting the user click, it's javascript/jQuery.

Note that PHP can also inject javascript along with the HTML - but once the code has been served to the browser for display, it is only the javascript that can interact with the user, not the PHP.

With javascript/jQuery, you can do what you want like this (the code is correct but the example will not work properly - SO will not navigate to the Google webpage):

```js
$('#myImg').click(function(){
  window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click below for Google</p>
<img id="myImg" src="http://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" />
```